# C# how to pass variables from form to userControl and viceversa

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

being a beginner of C # (WinForm) I am making graphical interfaces using a form inside which there is a container panel, in it at runtime I am going to open various user controls, which for me represent the various graphical pages.
First of all I would like to know if this is a good method to manage graphical interfaces, or if there are better ones.

Then I would like to understand what is the best way to pass the data between the main form and the usercontrol pages. I usually instantiate the objects as static, so that I can also see them from the userControls ...

Thanks

Comment: UserControls are meant to bundle a set of child controls in order to provide the functionality as well as the *various support methods* for some larger operation (such as a search function, add new product, add customer etc).  As such, most interaction is limited to those methods and events you write and expose.  In OOP it is called *encapsulation*.  It is possible you actually mean something else by 'user controls' though but we cant tell.

Answer (score 0):

Create properties in your user control so as to access the underlying data. I would advise against exposing any nested control in your user control.

Comment: Thanks, ok I'll add some properties. But in your opinion, I use UserControl as a GUI page. Is it ok? Or it's better use form and open it as MDI child... Are there some guideline about how to handle correctly GUI in C#?

Comment: You use a usercontrol when you do not want to keep repeating the same functionality over and over. Say you want to have 50 tru-color lights (green, orange, red) according to different ranges. The code is essentially the same except for the ranges. So the best in such case is to create a user control and use 50 instances of such usercontrol

Comment: ah ok perfect! and for GUI pages? I don't want to use popup form (with show() or showDialog()) I want to have single form container, and then open inside other page. What system are you using to handle change GUI pages?